# Using GitHub Pages, is it possible to specify the root web directory when not using Jekyll?

Tags: github-pages

I'm using another static site generator and I'd like to be able to check-in the source files (in markdown) as well as the generated site to my username.github.com repo.  So, much like Jekyll but I'm not using Jekyll.  My structure is:

```
--source
  1.md
  2.md
--target
  index.html
  1.html
  2.html
  --css
    app.css
index.html (GitHub Pages wants the root here)
```

GitHub Pages is serving the index.html and expects the rest of the site to be at the root.  I would like the site to be served from target/index.html.  This would allow me to create a source/3.md, generate it locally, and push both source/3.md and target/3.html.

The only ways I can think to do this is to:

1. have 2 repos - one for the markdown and generate to another for just the html.
2. have a branch that contains the markdown and commit the source to that branch and switch to master before committing the generated target html.
3. keep the markdown in the root (instead of 'source') and generate the html to the same root directory
4. as a long shot, adopt the Jekyll diretory structure and hope it doesn't interfere somehow by thinking it's a true Jekyll-style site

Comment: I just don't understand the design rationale they used! It seems they have a very tight coupling with Jekyll! Specifying a build directory would have made it possible to switch Jekyll with any static generators.

Comment: Redirection might help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32109398/375680

Answer (score 1):

reviewing the jekyll docs https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages it seems that isn't possible. The source directory can't be changed.